# Use let's encrypt certificates with the prometheus node exporter

Tags: linux, debian, https, lets-encrypt, prometheus

I'm trying to configure a prometheus node exporter with HTTPS using the website certificates generated by let's encrypt.

There is certificates with permissions default let's encrypt permission

But I have this error with node exporter service witch use the user 'node_exporter' :
failed to load X509KeyPair: open /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/fullchain.pem

The unit service :

```
[Unit]
Description=Node Exporter
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=node_exporter
Group=node_exporter
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/node_exporter/node_exporter --web.config.file=/opt/node_exporter/configuration.yml

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

has anyone already managed to use let's encrypt certificates to activate the node_exporter in HTTPS mode

Thank you in advance for help

Comment: It sounds like it's just a permissions issue (or the path is wrong). As the `node_exporter` user, can you access that certificate? What happens if you run `sudo -u node_exporter cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/fullchain.pem`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the directry `/etc/letsencrypt/archive` containing the keys & the certificates and the directory `/etc/letsencrypt/live` containing the symbolic links to the current certificate & key are only readable by the user `root` (`drwx------ root:root`). The services that can use those certificates have a process running as the root that *forks* processes as an unprivileged user.

You could copy the certificate & key to somewhere the user `node_exporter` is able to read them from. It would be best to do this in the renewal post-hook to keep it up-to-date. Also ensure that Node Exporter is either able to reload the updated files or make it reload/restart after the certificate has been renewed.